# Replace for loop with list comprehension

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
string = ""
for e in list:
    string += e
```

How would this for loop be expressed as a list comprehension so that it outputs a string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The preferred idiom for what you want is:

```
string = ''.join(l)
```

Explained: [**`join()`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is a string method that gets an *iterable* and returns a *string* with all elements in the iterable separated by the string it is called on. So, for example, `', '.join(['a', 'b'])` would simply return the string `'a, b'`. Since lists are iterables, we can pass them to `join` with the separator `''` (empty string) to concatenate all items in the list.

Note: since [`list`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) is the built-in type name for lists in Python, it's preferable not to mask it by naming a variable 'list'. Therefore, I've named the list in the example `l`.

Answer (score 3):

List comprehensions return lists not strings. Use join()

```
string = "".join(lst)
```

To understand the join method more fully, see: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Also, beware of naming a variable as `list` since it is a recognized type and will cause trouble down the line.

Answer (score 1):

not a list comprehension, but still short, hope works.

```
string = ''
list = ['a',' f' , 'f' ,'daf','fd']

x =reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, list, string)
print x
```